# Displaying plist based on variable

Tags: ios, nsarray, nsdictionary

I am currently displaying my plist using the code below, which works, however this seems inefficient to me and I presume there is a cleaner approach.

```
if ([self.title  isEqual: @"How to wear a Kilt"]){
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"wearAKilt" ofType:@"plist"];
    // Load the file content and read the data into arrays
    NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    thumbImg = [dict objectForKey:@"thumbImg"];
    stepLabel = [dict objectForKey:@"stepLabel"];
    descLabel = [dict objectForKey:@"descLabel"];
    }
    // Find out the path of recipes.plist
    else if ([self.title  isEqual: @"How to tie a cravat"]){
        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"wearACravat" ofType:@"plist"];
        // Load the file content and read the data into arrays
        NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
        thumbImg = [dict objectForKey:@"thumbImg"];
        stepLabel = [dict objectForKey:@"stepLabel"];
        descLabel = [dict objectForKey:@"descLabel"];
    }
    else if ([self.title  isEqual: @"How to wear a sporran"]){
        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"wearASporran" ofType:@"plist"];
        // Load the file content and read the data into arrays
        NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
        thumbImg = [dict objectForKey:@"thumbImg"];
        stepLabel = [dict objectForKey:@"stepLabel"];
        descLabel = [dict objectForKey:@"descLabel"];
    }
```

I have tried using a if statement just on the *path but this (as expected) produces a `undeclared identifier path` error.

```
if ([self.title  isEqual: @"How to wear a Kilt"]){
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"wearAKilt" ofType:@"plist"];
    } else if ([self.title  isEqual: @"How to tie a cravat"]) {
        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"wearACravat" ofType:@"plist"];
    }
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You second bit of code, just do:

```
NSString *path;

if ([self.title  isEqual: @"How to wear a Kilt"]){
    path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"wearAKilt" ofType:@"plist"];
} else if ([self.title  isEqual: @"How to tie a cravat"]) {
    path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"wearACravat" ofType:@"plist"];
}
```

You could also use a dictionary to map from the incoming string to the associated file name...

e.g.

```
NSDicttionary *mapping = @{
    @"How to wear a Kilt" : @"wearAKilt",
    @"How to tie a cravat" : @"wearACravat",
};
```

Which could be a static definition, and should probably consider localisation. Then:

```
NSString *name = [mapping objectForKey:self.title];
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:name ofType:@"plist"];
```

Comment: now i feel like a idiot. Simple. Out of interest is there any good documentation about how to  'use a dictionary to map from the incoming string to the associated file name'

Comment: im setting the title based on the table view from before using seagues

Comment: Added a quick snip of code. The keys should tie in with how you set the title ideally...